# Disable logging of Jenkins functions in Jenkins Blue Ocean

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-blueocean

When using the Jenkins functions `readJSON` and `httpRequest` in my groovy file for a Jenkins pipeline step, this gets shown as a row in Jenkins Blue. Is there any way to disable the logging of these steps? As they clutter the readability of the Jenkins blue pipeline.

[image]